# Ember.JS CLI - Show Preloading Page on Route

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-cli

I am new to ember.js and am trying to build a SPA webpage that uses a lot of images.

I am using Ember CLI, and I have one Route. In the route model, I preload the data, as well as preload about 30+ images using RSVP and Promises.

I have a DIV tag in my HBS file that contains my loading screen

`<div class="loading-screen"/>`

I would like to modify my route so that in the "afterModel" method, I hide the "loading-screen" div tag.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this? I am not sure how to reference the DIV tag and hide it from within the Route.

Thank you.

Comment: Consider using loading substates. That's what they're for.

Comment: Refer the docs here http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/